# Data Storage Question Help

Tags: notation, computer-science

Apologies if this question is in the wrong area, I'm fairly new here! 
I'm currently studying a Computer Science degree and I'm so bad at Maths I should probably be ashamed. I'm learning, but since I'm teaching myself, this next part I'm totally confused as to whether I'm right or wrong. Any help would be really advantageous!

> Question: An average of 48.8 million public photos were uploaded to the Flickr photo sharing website each month during 2013. If the average size of an uploaded photo is 3 MB, how much storage space does a month of uploaded public photos take up? Give your answer to 3.s.f in both Terabytes (TB) and bytes (b).

I know I have to use a scientific notation for this question but trying to work it out is confusing me! Here's what I've got so far!

```
1MB = 2^20 or 1,048,576
3MB = (2^20 x 3) or 3,145,728
```

So, to work out the above question

```
(2^20 x 3MB) x 48,800,000 (pictures)
=153,511,530,000,000 MB
```

To give my answer in TB (this is where I'm starting to get confused)

```
1 MB = 9.537109375E-7 TB
153,511,530,000,000 MB = 146405625.1934 TB
```

I suspect that the answer is right, I'm just not sure what the scientific notation is. I have no idea what E-7 means and I found that conversion from a [data conversion website.](http://www.unit-conversion.info/computer.html)

Then, when trying to convert it into bytes, I got some ridiculous number like

```
160968506081300000000
```

Basically, i'm one very confused lady right now!

I'd be very grateful for some insight and criticism into where I'm going wrong!

Many thanks in advance,
Chloe

Comment: As a computer science student, you should probably also familiarise yourself with [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) which you can also use on [this site](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) to make your posts look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

"E$N$" means "$*10^N$", so "E-7" means "$*10^{-7}$". Why do you think "160968506081300000000" is a ridicolous number? It's huge, but so is "153,511,530,000,000 MB".

Also be aware that in many cases (almost all regarding storage), prefix are based on powers of $10$, i.e. "MB" is "1.000.000 bytes" and so on.

Comment: Note also that there is a common notation to distinguish between powers of 10 or powers of 2. In this notation "MB" (megabytes) would mean $10^6$, whereas "MiB" (mebibytes) would mean $2^{20}$.